# How to scrape a JSON tag included deeply in a HTML Page

Tags: json, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape Amazon's Goldbox page by trying to extract the JSON object responsible for the deal details (dealdetails).

I've tried to extract all the JSON within the 40th script tag, however I came out with 15000 lines of code

The JSON within the page is like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">(function(f) {var _np=(window.P._namespace("GoldboxMobileMason"));if(_np.guardFatal){_np.guardFatal(f)(_np);}else{f(_np);}}(function(P) {

    window.gb = window.gb || {};

{
            "GDS" : {
               "baseRetryInterval" : 4000,
               "maxRetries" : 0,
               "ajaxTimeout" : 10000
            }
         },
         {
            "GD" : {
               "baseRetryInterval" : 4000,
               "maxRetries" : 1,
               "ajaxTimeout" : 10000
            }
         },
         {
            "WD" : {
               "baseRetryInterval" : 4000,
               "maxRetries" : 0,
               "ajaxTimeout" : 10000
            }
         }
"dealDetails" : {
      "3b009cf9" : {
         "egressUrl" : "https://www.amazon.com/Meredith-Martha-Stewart-Living/dp/B002PXW0EO",
         "maxDealPrice" : "5.49",
         "offerID" : 000      
         "maxPrevPrice" : "5.49",
         "minBAmount" : "49.9",

         "itemType" : "SINGLE_ITEM",
         "minPercentOff" : 89,
         "items" : [
         ]
      },
      "f87c994b" : {
         "egressUrl" : "https://www.amazon.com/s/?url=search-
         "reviewAsin" : "B073VYKTZN",
         "maxListPrice" : "159.99",
         "isMAP" : "0",
         "displayPriority" : "0",
         "isEligibleForFreeShipping" : "0",
         "isPrimeEligible" : "1",
         "dealID" : "f87c994b",
         "description" : "Save 50% on JUVEA All Natural Talalay Latex Pillows",

         "minBAmount" : "99.99",
         "currencyCode" : "USD",
         "minListPrice" : "129.99",
         "merchantID" : "A21VHZ1TV3ZUZI",
         "score" : "0",
         "bKind" : "OP",
         "msToFeatureEnd" : "0",

      },
"responseMetadata" : {
      "continueRetries" : "1",
      "baseRetryInterval" : "12000"
   }
};

        window.gb.controller.registerWidget(widgetToRegister);

    });

}));</script>
```

I tried using Regex but I think I'm doing it wrong:

```
    page = requests.get(primary_url, auth=('user', 'pass'), headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
    data  = soup.select("[type='text/javascript']")[40]
    raw = "dealdetails" + "\n".join(str(data.find("script")).split("\n")[4:-3])
    print(raw)
    json_obj = json.loads(raw)
```

The end result must be:

```
"dealDetails" : {
      "3b009cf9" : {
         "egressUrl" : "https://www.amazon.com/Meredith-Martha-Stewart-Living/dp/B002PXW0EO",
         "maxDealPrice" : "5.49",
         "offerID" : 000      
         "maxPrevPrice" : "5.49",
         "minBAmount" : "49.9",

         "itemType" : "SINGLE_ITEM",
         "minPercentOff" : 89,
         "items" : [
         ]
      },
      "f87c994b" : {
         "egressUrl" : "https://www.amazon.com/s/?url=search-
         "reviewAsin" : "B073VYKTZN",
         "maxListPrice" : "159.99",
         "isMAP" : "0",
         "displayPriority" : "0",
         "isEligibleForFreeShipping" : "0",
         "isPrimeEligible" : "1",
         "dealID" : "f87c994b",
         "description" : "Save 50% on JUVEA All Natural Talalay Latex Pillows",

         "minBAmount" : "99.99",
         "currencyCode" : "USD",
         "minListPrice" : "129.99",
         "merchantID" : "A21VHZ1TV3ZUZI",
         "score" : "0",
         "bKind" : "OP",
         "msToFeatureEnd" : "0",

      },
"responseMetadata" : {
      "continueRetries" : "1",
      "baseRetryInterval" : "12000"
   }
};
```

Comment: Are you sure about the json in the page shown in the question? It's not well formed; for example,  `"` and `,` are missing here and there.

Comment: @JackFleeting I removed a lot of code for this question because it's 15000 lines. So it may be some errors here and there because of that.

Comment: Got it. If it's ok with you, I can post an answer that assumes the json was fixed first so it's valid.

Comment: @JackFleeting ok that's good for me.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is:

```
re.search(r'^{.*?^}', script_content, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)[0]
```

but if the indenting is different you will need to adjust it.

Answer (score 0):

```
fixed_str = [your json above, fixed into valid json format]

target = fixed_str.replace("dealDetails",'xxx{ "dealDetails').split("xxx") #this splits the script tag by first removing preceding irrelevant stuff 
final = target[1].replace("}\n};","}}\n}xxx").split('xxx') #this splits it again by dropping trailing irrelevant stuff

json_obj = json.loads(final[0])
json_obj
```

And, if all works well :), it should get you  your desired end result...

Comment: If json was well formed it would not be a problem for me. The page that I want to scrape is amazon.com/goldbox
Take a look to know what I mean.
The object I need called "dealdetails"

Comment: @AmineKhaoui - As I mentioned in a comment to your question - this ASSUMES the json in the document is well formed. You said it's ok to assume it. This is different question now.